# JSON manipulation - javascript - adding new keys and shifting data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm learning to manipulate JSON data and I am stuck trying to figure out how to cajole the following JSON into what I want as shown below:

Any pointers to function/terms/concepts that I should learn for this sort of problem would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

**JSON object**

```
{
  car: 1,
  van: 5,
  cat: 99999999999999999999999
}
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
items: [ 
  { "type": "car", "value": "1"},
  { "type": "van", "value": "5"},
  { "type": "cat", "value": "99999999999999999999999"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const obj = { car: 1, van: 5, cat: 99999999999999999999999 };

let list = Object.entries(obj)  // [["car",1],["van",5],["cat",99999999999999999999999]]
    .map(x => ({ type: x[0], value: x[1] }));

console.log(list);
```

Or, with some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring):

```js
const obj = { car: 1, van: 5, cat: 99999999999999999999999 };

let list = Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([type, value]) => ({ type, value }));

console.log(list);
```

The callback to `map`:

```
([type, value]) => ({ type, value })
```

Expects an array as parameter: `[type, value]`. The first value in that array is assigned to `type`, the second one to `value`.

Then we use a [shorthand form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to set these values in our returned object:

```
=> ({ type, value })
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys will return: 
`['car', 'van', 'cat']`;

On this array you can use Array's map function which creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
        var a = {
          car: 1,
          van: 5,
          cat: 99999999999999999999999
        }

        m = Object.keys(a).map((v)=>{
          return {
            type: v,
            value: a[v]
          }
        })

        console.log(m);
```

@GustavMahler hope you understand. To learn more about array functions you should look map, reduce and filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner. I tried to solve the problem and this is the best I can come up with, tested in Node.js 10.

```
const obj = {"car": 1, "van": 5, "cat": 999999}
const items = []
for (let key in obj) {
    items.push({"type": key, "value": obj[key]})
}
console.log(items)
```

One thing I am slightly confused about is the difference between for..in vs for..of, I'm currently looking into it.

Answer (score -1):

This one uses object.keys

```
let js = {car:1, van:5, cat:9999}
Object.keys(js).map( x => ({type: x, value: js[x] }) )
[ { type: 'car', value: 1 },
  { type: 'van', value: 5 },
  { type: 'cat', value: 9999 } ]
```